# How to dynamically create a form based on submitting the first form

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

For eg:
1) I have one text box and submit button if a person adds the value and select submit button then this text box value will be sent to java program where internal calculations will be made and returned to the JSP page based on the values new form should be dynamically created on same page and this form should have the value of the text box which is created before and if i submit it should send all the values to java program...

Please post me a sample code of jsp and java program asap

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly this is how your data flow would look like?

HTML Form Data --> Java Servlet --> HTML Data ?

The approach I would, is by using Java Beans to populate your data. They are just normal java class with private fields, getters and setters to store value.
Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/) for more information

Form

```
<form action"YourServlet">
<!-- Your input e.g username and submit button -->
</form>
```

SERVLET

```
//request data
//do your calculation
//populate bean
//dispatch to jsp
```

BEAN

```
//private field correspond to your form data value e.g userName
//constructor no arg
//getters and setters
//other methods
```

JSP

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="package.BeanClass" scope="session"/>
Value:
<jsp:getProperty name="bean's id" property="property name"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Jabberbyter, I need a value to get processed from a java program in JSP page and it should be sent to the next jsp page, even that page will communicate to different method of the same java program, can you please provide me the sample program of the above concept it will help me in case of alternative

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking to solve HW problems. I therefore cannot help you further. I suggest you read on Java Beans, servlets and MVC. The key idea is to use java beans to 'store' your data so you can bounce the value between JSP pages and java programs. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

wrote 3 jsp with an external java file which solved the issue:
1- first jsp
2- second jsp
3- deciding jsp
4- java

Comment: This answer needs more detail to be useful to others.